# UISearchDisplayController and setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm struggling with the `UISearchDisplayController` and hope someone out there can help me out.

So basically I've got a `UINavigationBar` which has a "Search"-Button in it. When someone taps "Search" the `UISearchDisplayController` should get active and the UISearchBar should appear inside the `UINavigationBar`. Next to the SearchBar I've implemented a "Cancel"-Button which deactivates the `SearchDisplayController` and resets the `UINavigationBar` back to it's standard with the "Search"-Button.

[image: Default UINavigationBar]

My first problem is the gap between my `SearchBar` and the results-table or the gray overlay while the `SearchDisplayController` is active.

[image: SearchBar activated]

The second problem is that I can't reset my rightBarButtonItem to the default icon (magnifying-glass) after tapping cancel. It's nothing happening even when I try to set `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];`  it just remains with the "Cancel" button.

[image: after clicking Cancel]

Here is my implementation: (The UI elements are added through my storyboard)

```
- (IBAction)btnSearchClicked:(id)sender {
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelEditing)];

[self.searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 44)];
[self.searchController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];
[self.searchController setActive:YES animated:YES];
[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)cancelEditing
{
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
[self.searchController setActive:NO animated:YES];
[self.searchController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I came up with a solution for both problems.

The gap was occurring because of `[self.searchController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];` which expected the NavigationBar to be translucent, so I've worked around by just enabling translucency on `btnSearchClicked` and deactivating it on cancel.

The problem with the button was resolved by deactivating `setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` in `cancelEditing` before accessing the `setRightBarButtonItem` property. Maybe that the `setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar`-Option creates an new NavigationBar which doesn't respond to self.navigationItem.